# Leak when run subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

When I run this I get a leak. I am not sure what it is happening. I guess pipe does not close or might be something else happening.

```
def deactivateMetadataDevice(input_dmd_lun_wwn):
    #print('pvremove /dev/mapper/' + input_dmd_lun_wwn)
    status_cmd = False
    ps = subprocess.Popen('/sbin/pvremove /dev/mapper/' + input_dmd_lun_wwn, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in iter(ps.stdout.readline, ''):
        print line
        if re.search('wiped', line):
           status_cmd = True
        else:
           # Cleaning metadata and removing from LVM if ok then return true
           status_cmd = False
           raise Warning('\t\t PV /dev/mapper/'+ input_dmd_lun_wwn +' belongs to Volume Group')

    return status_cmd
```

Getting this issue when I run the code above:

```
File descriptor 4 (pipe:[323948]) leaked on pvremove invocation. Parent PID 15380: python
```

Comment: This code raises an exception on the first line that doesn't have the word 'wiped' in it, then abandons the process completely. This is pvremove, so you should let it finish its job by continuing to read stdout and then do a ps.wait(). Then you can raise your warning.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you return before reading all of the data in the pipe and you don't issue a wait to get the return code and remove the process from the operating system pid table. I think a few tweaks will do it (I also removed a few things I thought were redundant).

```
def deactivateMetadataDevice(input_dmd_lun_wwn):
    #print('pvremove /dev/mapper/' + input_dmd_lun_wwn)
    status_cmd = False
    ps = subprocess.Popen('/sbin/pvremove /dev/mapper/' + input_dmd_lun_wwn, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in ps.stdout:
        print line
        if 'wiped' in line:
           status_cmd = True
    ps.wait()
    # need to handle ps.returncode != 0
    if status_cmd is False:
       # Cleaning metadata and removing from LVM if ok then return true
       raise Warning('\t\t PV /dev/mapper/'+ input_dmd_lun_wwn +' belongs to Volume Group')
    return status_cmd # likely not needed because you are using exceptions for errors
```

Comment: also, since you don't perform interactive communication with the subprocess, you should use `subprocess.check_output` -- it checks for the `returncode` automatically, collects `stdout` and returns it, and when it returns, you can be sure that the process ended in one way or another

Comment: @dnet is right, there are several ways to handle it. With check_output, you'll need to handle the error raised if the process returns non-zero. Popen.communicate is another perennial favorite.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old, but I ran into a similar problem and thought my answer might help anyone else stumbling onto this while searching for help.

The default for subprocess.Popen is close_fds=False (ETA: The default was changed to True on POSIX in Python 3.2). But the lvm(8) man page states:

> On invocation, lvm requires that only the standard file descriptors stdin, stdout
>   and stderr are available. If others are found, they get closed and messages
>   are issued warning about the leak.

So for lvm commands like pvremove, you can avoid the leak by setting close_fds=True in your subprocess.Popen call.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Oh, you're right. I will edit my answer to be clearer about that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this way. Unfortunately most of servers in env have python 2.6. Check_output comes with python 2.7 version.

```
# check_output in subprocess unfortunately comes by default in 2.7 version
def check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs):
    # Passing all arguments to process
    process = subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    output, unused_err = process.communicate()
    retcode = process.poll()

    if retcode:
       cmd = kwargs.get("args")
       if cmd is None:
          cmd = popenargs[0]
       error = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
       error.output = output
       raise error

    return output

# Function to remove metadata from phisical device
def deactivateMetadataDevice(input_dmd_lun_wwn):
    #print('pvremove /dev/mapper/' + input_dmd_lun_wwn)
    status_cmd = False
    if 'wiped' in check_output(["/sbin/pvremove", "/dev/mapper/" + input_dmd_lun_wwn]):
       status_cmd = True

    return status_cmd
```